# Mostar imagem do Banco Mysql com 2ids diferentes mas campo em comum em PHP

Tags: php, imagem

Possuo uma pagina cadastro_cartao.php

Nessa pagina tenho INPUTS para inserir Nome, CPF, Telefone Contato, mais um INPUT tipo File para a pessoa colocar foto dos documentos e foto do comprovante de residência.

Quando Clica em enviar ele insere as informações no Banco de dados mas gera um Id para cada imagem que a pessoa inseriu ou seja

Se o CPF 111.111.111-85 inseriu o Nome, o CPF, o Telefone e 2 Imagens no BD 
 o Mysql inseriu desta maneira:

ID: 1 / Foto: Foto1 / Nome: ALEX / CPF: 111.111.111-85 / Telefone: xx xxxxxxxxx

ID: 2 / Foto: Foto2 / Nome: ALEX / CPF: 111.111.111-85 / Telefone: xx xxxxxxxxx

Esta inserindo corretamente no BD

Tenho uma outra Página que faz Análise dos Documentos enviados chamada analise_cartao.php

Onde sob uma consulta no Banco traz os dados agrupados por CPF

Ou seja na apresentação na página não é mostrado as imagens mas mostra os dados agrupado por CPF e fica desta maneira

Nome: ALEX / CPF: 111.111.111-85 / Telefone: xx xxxxxxxxx

Nessa pagina analise_cartao.php tenho um link
`<a href='ver-cad-cartao.php?cpf=$res_sql[cpf]' title='Ver'><img src='imagem/bg-view.fw.png'></a>`
onde passo por parâmetro no link o cpf para ver o cadastro completo:

Minha duvida é :
Como fazer a página ver-cad-cartao.php carregar as imagens vinculadas nesse cpf, pois no código que fiz só apresenta a imagem de id 1, e não as duas id1 e id2 que quero.

Código da página ver-cad-cartao.php

```
<?php
require_once("../funcoes/conexao.php"); 
$cpf = $_GET['cpf'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faca_cartao where cpf='$cpf'") or die (mysql_error());  
$res_sql = mysql_fetch_array($sql);{
echo '  
<div>       
<img  src="../cartao/'.$res_sql["document_name"].'" width="300px">
</div>  ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Você pode fazer assim
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faca_cartao where cpf='$cpf'") or die (mysql_error());  

$rowsfound = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($rowsfound > 0)
{
  $count = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '  
<div>       
  <img  src="../cartao/'.$row[$count]["document_name"].'" width="300px">
</div>  ';
$count++;
}
}
```

Comment: testei mas agora nem aparece a primeira imagem